# CanCan, different between index and show?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I have the following in ability.rb

```
  can :index, Thread

  can :show, Thread do |thread|
    1 == 2
  end
```

I hard coded show to result as false to test a fail. Shockingly, show never fails. Both Thread index and Thread show both return without resulting in a CanCan access denied. What's going on with that? Suggestions? Thx

Comment: Try using `cannot` instead of `can` and skip the block just to see if its an issue with that. Also, I believe Thread is used for a core Ruby class, I'm not sure if that would be interfering here.

Comment: Is there anything above these lines? If I remember correctly, any abilities defined first take priority.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As can be seen [here](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/blob/master/lib/cancan/ability.rb#L292) `:index` and `:show` are aliases of `:read`, that means they are synonyms.

When you say `can :index, Thread` that means the user will be able to read anything.
When you later define second rule `can :show, Thread {|t| 1 == 2}`, the CanCan query for successive rules is disjunctive, that is `result = rule1 or rule2`. To have the result computed via difference `result = rule1 - rule2` use `cannot` for the 2nd rule:

```
cannot :show, Thread {|t| 1 == 2}
```